# TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface Py2 to Py3

Tags: string, python-2.7, python-3.4, compatibility, backwards-compatibility

I have a program written in Python 2 which I would like to get running for Python 3. I'm getting

> TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

on the following code:

```
_head = _head.rstrip('\0').upper()
```

I believe I understand the main reason for the error, however none of the solutions I found here so far worked for me. The outcome of all this is `b'variable'`, which messes up the rest of the program. The outcome in Python 2 is just `variable`. Can I get the same result in Python 3?

Comment: What is `_head`?  Where is the code that created it?

Comment: It goes something like this:
_head, _value = struct.unpack('<32s96s', file.read(128))

_head = _head.rstrip(b'\0').upper()

self._fHeader[_head] = _value.rstrip('\0')

Generally, the program is meant to read a binary file and get a set of keywords:values from it

Comment: Solved it. The line I posted got fixed by using: ...rstrip(b'\0')..., but note that later on in the program I had to be aware at all times what type of data I'm using (adding that 'b' where necessary). Adding the 'b' to just the line I posted removed the error from the line, but caused other problems later on (i.e. the program was trying to reach b'string' instead of just 'string)